# #error when summing numbers in report builder?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to sum some numbers up in a grouping, and sometimes a `#error` would show up instead of an actual number. I understand that this may happen when dividing by 0 or when there are nulls in the dataset, but in the dataset, I only see valid numbers. The numbers aren't large enough to cause an overflow, and I'm certain the expression is correct, as the `#error` only shows up for a particular combination of parameters.

Is there another reason why I'm seeing the `#error` message?

To be clear, the formula is `=Sum(Fields!Number.Value)`

**Edit:** Any of the aggregation functions also result in this message.

Answer (score 28):

Sometimes SSRS decides that a number field returned from the dataset is text. Then many VB functions will fail.

See if converting the number to a decimal fixes things:

```
=SUM(CDEC(Fields!Number.Value))
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. Is this a documented bug in Report Builder? Edit: I spoke too soon it seems. It fixed the problem when using a specific set of parameters, but another parameter produces this problem again :(

Comment: Are you sure that this field is really a number for all rows returned?

Comment: Yes, in the query designer, they're all numbers. I've also replaced all the null values with 0's.

Comment: This answer saved me!

Comment: You saved my ass , Thanks

Comment: When after searching for an hour for a solution to a nonsensicial problem an answer suddenly works. Thanks a bunch!